# form_for can't get edit/update and show/new working together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My form_for started out like this.

```
<%= form_for([@memberlisting.membercontact, @memberlisting], url: backend_membercontact_memberlistings_path) do |f| %>
```

I had a problem with edit/updates with a routing error.

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/backend/membercontacts/1/memberlistings"
```

Through another question there was a fix with method: :patch plus backend_membercontact_memberlisting(s)_path removed the s and I can update things.

```
<%= form_for([@memberlisting.membercontact, @memberlisting], url: backend_membercontact_memberlisting_path, method: :patch) do |f| %>
```

Now show/new is giving out error where it didn't before.

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"backend/memberlistings", :membercontact_id=>"1"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I'm think putting method patch at the end is causing the above error, but how can I get both show/new + edit/update to work?

Some additional information

routes.rb

```
# Application Client Backend
namespace :backend do
    # Member Routes
    resources :membercontacts do
        resources :memberaddresses
        resources :memberlistings
    end
end
```

backend/memberlisting.rb

```
class Backend::Memberlisting < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Model Relationships
    belongs_to :membercontact

end
```

backend/membercontact.rb

```
class Backend::Membercontact < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Model Relationship
    has_many :memberlistings, dependent: :destroy

end
```

backend/memberlistings_controller.rb

```
class Backend::MemberlistingsController < ApplicationController

    # Security & Action Filters
    layout '/backend/application.html.erb'
    before_action :set_memberlisting, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    # Member Listing Index
    def index
        membercontact = Backend::Membercontact.find(params[:membercontact_id])
        @memberlistings = membercontact.memberlistings.order('mlcontactname ASC')
    end

    # Detailed Member Listing Profile
    def show
        membercontact = Backend::Membercontact.find(params[:membercontact_id])
        @membercontact = membercontact.memberlistings.find(params[:id])
    end

    # New Member Listing
    def new
        membercontact = Backend::Membercontact.find(params[:membercontact_id])
        @memberlisting = membercontact.memberlistings.build
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # new.html.erb
            format.xml  { render :xml => @membercontact }
        end
    end

    # Edit Member Listing
    def edit
        membercontact = Backend::Membercontact.find(params[:membercontact_id])
        @memberlisting = membercontact.memberlistings.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Create Member Listing Action
    def create
        @membercontact = Backend::Membercontact.find(params[:membercontact_id])
        @memberlisting = @membercontact.memberlistings.create(memberlisting_params)
        respond_to do |format|
        if @memberlisting.save
            format.html { redirect_to backend_membercontact_memberlistings_path, notice: 'Address for Membercontact was Successfully Created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @memberlisting }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'new' }
                format.json { render json: @memberlisting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # Update Member Listing Action
    def update
        respond_to do |format|
        if @memberlisting.update(memberlisting_params)
            format.html { redirect_to backend_membercontact_memberlistings_path, notice: 'Address for Membercontact was Successfully Updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'edit' }
                format.json { render json: @memberlisting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # Delete Member Listing Action
    def destroy
        @membercontact = Backend::Membercontact.find(params[:membercontact_id])
        @memberlisting = @membercontact.memberlistings.find(params[:id])
        @memberlisting.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to backend_membercontact_memberlistings_path, notice: 'Address for Membercontact was Successfully Deleted.'  }
            format.json { head :no_content }
        end
    end

    private

    def set_memberlisting
        @memberlisting = Backend::Memberlisting.find(params[:id])
    end

    def memberlisting_params
        params.require(:backend_memberlisting).permit(:mlcontactname, :mlcompanyname, :mladdressline1, :mladdressline2, :mlcity, :mlprovince, :mlpostalcode, :mlphone, :mlwebsite, :mlemail, :membercontact_id, :account_id)
    end

end
```

Routes Rake

```
backend_membercontact_memberlistings_path       GET /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings(.:format)  backend/memberlistings#index
                                                POST    /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings(.:format)  backend/memberlistings#create
new_backend_membercontact_memberlisting_path    GET /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/new(.:format)  backend/memberlistings#new
edit_backend_membercontact_memberlisting_path   GET /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id/edit(.:format) backend/memberlistings#edit
backend_membercontact_memberlisting_path        GET /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id(.:format)  backend/memberlistings#show
                                                PATCH   /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id(.:format)  backend/memberlistings#update
                                                PUT /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id(.:format)  backend/memberlistings#update
                                                DELETE  /backend/membercontacts/:membercontact_id/memberlistings/:id(.:format)  backend/memberlistings#destroy
```

I like to keep everything nested the way it is. I can't figure out why crud functions are giving me problems, if I take out the patch method it won't update but when I put the patch method in it won't create a new or show record b/c of missing id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `form_for` has the URL option specified, which means that it's always going to route to that path using the objects provided in the `records` argument. The path you've listed is compatible with existing objects, but it does not match a `new` object, which doesn't yet have an `ID`.

You also can't specify PATCH, because it's always going to use that even when that method doesn't exist.

You also need to include your namespace in the `form_for` `records` argument, so it would look pretty close to the following:

`<%= form_for([:backend, @memberlisting.membercontact, @memberlisting]) do |f| %>`

Give that a shot and see if it works. You can read more about the form_for helper [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for).

Comment: Thanks. I think last time it kept trying to find. backend_membercontact_backend_memberlistings  I'll give it a try though.

Comment: Hmmmm, riiiight. I think I remember this being a bit hairy now that I think about it. If memory serves I had to call a separate form_for in the edit and new pages, and then include the form elements as a partial.

Comment: Do you think in the routes file there's a way to remove the namespace from the nested resources? I may also just do scope module: as I had an easier time with that.

Comment: I gave credit because your answer prevented me from going down the wrong path and hopefully I can figure out a solution with your second comment. Appreciate it.

Comment: I think scoping could be the way to go. Depends on whether you'd run into a conflict with other routes. Either way, it's a bit hairy but it's easier to do the two form_fors then trying to override this in whichever way is appropriate.

Comment: No problem thanks for getting me back on the right path.